# Android Path + Tracing Alphabets

Tags: java, android, gestures

I'm trying to trace the Path 'A'

I came across tutorials for creating gestures.

But i couldn't figure it how to enable such gestures only for a specified portion.

Also the Gestures must be on a specific path ? How to set such a constraint ?